# Can vue routes have a default value for a parameter?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Imagine a route with the following path: ':uuid*/form/:step'

Can we specify the default value of the step parameter, on the router definition?

I've tried setting this value on the view's created function but I'm trying to avoid a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something like this using [router navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html):

```js
routes = [
  {
    name: 'FormStep',
    path: ':uuid*/form/:step'
    beforeEnter(route) {
      return { 
        path: route.path, 
        params: {
          ...route.params,
          step: route.params.step ?? defaultStep
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short anwser is: no you can't.

If the user goes to `:uuid/form`, you have to redirect him with the default step value. But if the `/uuid/form` page points to the same page component, the redirection won't cause a re-render, so it's almost transparent from the user point of view.

If you control the navigation to this page, just set a default value yourself in the code if it's not present:

```js
const step = userStep || 'defaultStep'
this.$router.push(`/${myUuid}/form/${step}`)
```